# can't login by Auth::attempt method

Tags: php, laravel

Ilearn laravel nearly and need some help in my problem 
I need to login but i can't > it always give me false 
 any help !! i don't know the  problem in bcrypt or what ?

## Auth::attempt() always false why ?

```
    <?php


      namespace App\Http\Controllers;
      use Illuminate\Http\Request;

      use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
      use App\User;

      class UserController extends Controller
      {
        public function getBoard(){

          return view('dashboard');
        }

        //sin up function

        public function postSignUp(Request $request)
       {

             $email = $request['email'];
             $First_Name = $request['First_Name'];
             $password = \Hash::make($request['password']);
             $user = new User();
             $user->email = $email;
             $user->First_Name = $First_Name;
             $user->password = $password;
             $user->save();

             Auth::login($user);

             return redirect()->route('dashboard');

      }    //sin in function
      public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
      $email =  $request['email'];
      $password = $request['password'];

      if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email,
       'password' => "123" ])) {
          return redirect()->route('dashboard');
      }
      echo  "not working";
    }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using "123" as the password you pass to Auth::attempt... Should you not do this instead?

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
 {
   $email =  $request['email'];
   $password = $request['password'];

   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password ])) {
      return redirect()->route('dashboard');
   }
   echo  "not working";
 }
```

Comment: " 123 " it just for testing

Comment: public function postSignIn(Request $request)
 {
   $email =  $request['email'];
   $password = $request['password'];

   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password ])) {
      return redirect()->route('dashboard');
   }
   echo  "not working";
 }
NOt working also , it give me also "not working"